# How to get an object's property's value by property name?

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, how do you get an object's property value by specifying its name (a string)? I want something like the following:

```
$obj = get-something

# View the object's members:
$obj | gm

# I could retrieve a property by doing so:
write-host $obj.SomeProp

# But for many purposes, I would really want to:
write-host $obj | Get-PropertyByName "SomeProp"
```

Is there something similar to "Get-PropertyByName" in PowerShell?

Answer (score 293, accepted):

Sure

```
write-host ($obj | Select -ExpandProperty "SomeProp")
```

Or for that matter:

```
$obj."SomeProp"
```

Comment: remember expand: `select -expand "SomeProp"` if you want the value. `select "SomeProp"` returns a customobject with a property "SomeProp", and then he's pretty much back at step 1.

Comment: Is there a way to use `$obj."SomeProp"` in `write-host`?

Comment: @TheMuffinMan, yes, it is a generally applicable feature, like write-host $obj."$somepropertyname"

Comment: When your string is in a variable, `$obj.($propName)` also works. (The parentheses are not required, but it looks *really* weird to me without them.)

Comment: If you have the `$propName` stored in a object for example `$Headers.PropertyName` then the parentheses are required `$obj.($Headers.PropertyName)`.

Comment: I personally like:  
**write-host "$($obj.SomeProp)"**

Comment: Can I do that for multiple properties in one line?

Answer (score 71):

Expanding upon @aquinas:

```
Get-something | select -ExpandProperty PropertyName
```

or

```
Get-something | select -expand PropertyName
```

or

```
Get-something | select -exp PropertyName
```

I made these suggestions for those that might just be looking for a single-line command to obtain some piece of information and wanted to include a real-world example.

In managing Office 365 via PowerShell, here was an example I used to obtain all of the users/groups that had been added to the "BookInPolicy" list:

```
Get-CalendarProcessing conferenceroom@example.com | Select -expand BookInPolicy
```

Just using "Select BookInPolicy" was cutting off several members, so thank you for this information!

Answer (score 38):

You can get a **property** by name using the `Select-Object` cmdlet and specifying the property name(s) that you're interested in. Note that this doesn't simply return the raw value for that property; instead you get something that still behaves like an object.

```
[PS]> $property = (Get-Process)[0] | Select-Object -Property Name

[PS]> $property

Name
----
armsvc

[PS]> $property.GetType().FullName
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
```

In order to use the **value** for that property, you will still need to identify which property you are after, even if there is only one property:

```
[PS]> $property.Name
armsvc

[PS]> $property -eq "armsvc"
False

[PS]> $property.Name -eq "armsvc"
True

[PS]> $property.Name.GetType().FullName
System.String
```

As per other answers here, if you want to use a single property within a string, you need to evaluate the expression (put brackets around it) and prefix with a dollar sign ($) to declare the expression dynamically as a variable to be inserted into the string:

```
[PS]> "The first process in the list is: $($property.Name)"
The first process in the list is: armsvc
```

Quite correctly, others have answered this question by recommending the `-ExpandProperty` parameter for the `Select-Object` cmdlet. This bypasses some of the headache by returning the value of the property specified, but you will want to use different approaches in different scenarios.

> `-ExpandProperty <String>`
>
> Specifies a property to select, and indicates that an attempt should
>   be made to expand that property
>
> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx

```
[PS]> (Get-Process)[0] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
armsvc
```

[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) [variables](/questions/tagged/variables)

Answer (score 18):

Try this :

```
$obj = @{
    SomeProp = "Hello"
}

Write-Host "Property Value is $($obj."SomeProp")"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please edit your question and explain *why* he should try this and *why* it improves the already existing answers.

Comment: I'm conflicted on upvote versus downvote because this answer is IMO the most simple way to safely get a property based on having the string name of the property from an object but also doesn't offer any explanation.

Comment: ```
$obj = @{ Prop = "Value"; };

$propName = "Prop"';
Write-Host "The value of $propName is $($obj."$propName")"

$propName = "NonexistentProp"';
Write-Host "The value of $propName is $($obj."$propName")"
```
will print  
`The value of Prop is Value`  
and then
`The value of NonexistentProp is `

Comment: WOW! the markdown documentation is linked in the help for comments but doesn't apply to them. really nice SO devs

Answer (score 8):

Here is an alternative way to get an object's property value:

```
write-host $(get-something).SomeProp
```

Comment: Works with propname held in a variable: `
$someprop = "SomeProp";
write-host $(get-something).$someprop`

Answer (score 0):

```
$com1 = new-object PSobject                                                         #Task1
$com2 = new-object PSobject                                                         #Task1
$com3 = new-object PSobject                                                         #Task1



$com1 | add-member noteproperty -name user -value jindpal                           #Task2
$com1 | add-member noteproperty -name code -value IT01                              #Task2
$com1 | add-member scriptmethod ver {[system.Environment]::oSVersion.Version}       #Task3


$com2 | add-member noteproperty -name user -value singh                             #Task2
$com2 | add-member noteproperty -name code -value IT02                              #Task2
$com2 | add-member scriptmethod ver {[system.Environment]::oSVersion.Version}       #Task3


$com3 | add-member noteproperty -name user -value dhanoa                             #Task2
$com3 | add-member noteproperty -name code -value IT03                               #Task2
$com3 | add-member scriptmethod ver {[system.Environment]::oSVersion.Version}        #Task3


$arr += $com1, $com2, $com3                                                          #Task4


write-host "windows version of computer1 is: "$com1.ver()                            #Task3
write-host "user name of computer1 is: "$com1.user                                   #Task6
write-host "code of computer1 is: "$com1,code                                        #Task5
write-host "windows version of computer2 is: "$com2.ver()                            #Task3
write-host "user name of computer2 is: "$com2.user                                   #Task6
write-host "windows version of computer3 is: "$com3.ver()                            #Task3
write-host "user name of computer3 is: "$com1.user                                   #Task6
write-host "code of computer3 is: "$com3,code                                        #Task5

read-host
```

Comment: $arr =@("jind",12, "singh")
write-host $arr[1]
read-host
$arr += "reza"
write-host $arr[3]
read-host
write-host $arr[$arr.length-1]
read-host
$arr = $arr -ne $arr[1]
write-host $arr
read-host

foreach ($i in $arr)
{write-host $i}