# How to extract just the info I need from powershell output

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to only extra the info you need from a script output?

I have the following:

```
Get-RetinaVersion | Select-Object Audits 

Audits
------
3536
```

I'm trying to isolate the "3536", I don't need the word Audits as part of the output.  Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Try this: `(Get-RetinaVersion).Audits`

Comment: May be be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406315/how-to-get-an-objects-propertys-value-by-property-name-in-powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
(Get-RetinaVersion).Audits
```

This should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it,

```
Get-RetinaVersion | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Audits
```