# How do I return only the integer from Measure-Object in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, measure-object

I would like to run a piece of code that counts how many characters are in a text file and save it as another text file but I need the output to only be a number.

This is the code I run in PowerShell:

`Get-Content [File location] | Measure-Object -Character | Out-File -FilePath [Output Location]`

and it saves the output like this:

```
Lines Words Characters Property
----- ----- ---------- --------
                     1
```

Is there any way to save just the number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic powershell:

```
(Get-Content file | Measure-Object -Character).characters
```

or

```
Get-Content file | Measure-Object -Character | select -expand characters
```

Related:  [How to get an object's property's value by property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406315/how-to-get-an-objects-propertys-value-by-property-name)

Answer (score -1):

Anything is an object in PowerShell, that goes for the result of Measure-Object as well. To get just the value of a property, use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty <PropertyName>`to get the desired properties Value;

```
PS> Get-ChildItem | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
PS> 3
```

In your example:

```
PS> Get-Content [File location] | 
    Measure-Object | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count | 
    Out-File -FilePath [Output Location]
```