# Is it possible to have powershell curl output only the content part?

Tags: windows, powershell

I ran this command from powershell on win10

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/ -UseBasicParsing
```

and got lots of info

[image]

Is it possible to have the powershell curl output only the content part pointed out by the red rectangle above?

I tried `findstr` which is not that satisfying.

[image]

Comment: Voting to migrate the question to SO so it can be closed as a duplicate to the linked question.

Comment: `curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/ -UseBasicParsing | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content`?

Comment: @JosefZ Thank you. That's exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an object's property's value by property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406315/how-to-get-an-objects-propertys-value-by-property-name) (per @GeraldSchneider's comment)

Comment: just `(curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/ -UseBasicParsing).Content`